# Restrict user access to a certain model and all of its relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

What is the best way to prevent certain users from accessing certain data without a direct relationship between the user and the model in Laravel?

For Example:
Let's say that we have two kinds of users (normal users, and restricted users), Also we have a model for blogs that have many comments and these comments have many replies.

Some of these blogs are flagged as premium blogs.

The normal users should be able to access all the blogs (without considering the premium flag), while restricted users should only access blogs that are not premium. and therefore they should not have access to any comments or replies that belongs to a premium blog.

The closest solution I have found until this moment is [Global Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes), which requires editing all the models that belong to the blog model.

So is there another method to implement this restriction without refactoring all the models?

Comment: Check out Policies in Laravel - its what they do. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.